# How can I use that code in Wordpress Post?

Tags: wordpress

I want to use that code in Wordpress Post.

When I use that code without Wordpress, it works. I mean I created a php file and pasted this code in it. And it works. But it doesn't work in Wordpress post.

What should I do?

Please help me about that. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
textarea { resize: none; }
.hide{ display: none; }
#popupoverlay { background-color: #000000; bottom: 0px; display: none; left: 0px; opacity: .75; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; }
#popupwindow { background-color: #FAFAD2; border: solid 2px #cccccc; display: none; height: 150px; left: 50%; margin: -75px 0 0 -35px; position: absolute; left: 350px; top: 80px; width: 800px; height: 630px }
#popupwindow a { background-color: #ff3333; display: block; font-size: 9px; height: 20px; left: 50%; margin: -309px 0 0 370px; position: absolute; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; top: 50%; width: 25px; }
#popupwindow h1 { background-color: #cccccc; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 3px 5px; text-align: center; }
#popupwindow p { font-size: 9pt; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; }
body{font: 9pt Verdana;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:-10}
td{font: 9pt Verdana;}
th{font: 9pt Verdana; text-align: left; font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<SCRIPT>
function checkEmail(myForm) {
if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.email.value)){
return (true)
}
alert("Please check your email.")
return (false)
}
//  End -->
</script>
<script>
function SayiKontrol(e) {
    olay = document.all ? window.event : e;
    tus = document.all ? olay.keyCode : olay.which;
    if(tus<48||tus>57) {
        if(document.all) { olay.returnValue = false; } else { olay.preventDefault(); }
    }
}

function HarfKontrol(e) {
    olay = document.all ? window.event : e;
    tus = document.all ? olay.keyCode : olay.which;
    if(tus>=48&&tus<=57) {
        if(document.all) { olay.returnValue = false; } else { olay.preventDefault(); }
    }
}
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPopup() {
        document.getElementById('PopupOverlay').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('PopupWindow').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function ClosePopup() {
        document.getElementById('PopupOverlay').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('PopupWindow').style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function HostingSpec(rad){
 var rads=document.getElementsByName(rad.name);
 var all=['first_giz','first_giz_1','second_giz']
 var ary=[
  ['first_giz','first_giz_1'],
  ['second_giz']
 ]
 for (var z0=0;z0<all.length;z0++){
  document.getElementById(all[z0]).style.display='none';
 }
 for (var z1a,z1=0;z1<rads.length;z1++){
  if (rads[z1].checked&&ary[z1]){
   for (z1a=0;z1a<ary[z1].length;z1a++){
    document.getElementById(ary[z1][z1a]).style.display='block';
   }
   return;
  }
 }

}
/*]]>*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="submit.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return checkEmail(this)">
       <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="OpenPopup();"><img border="0" src="submit.jpg"></a>
    </p>

    <div id="PopupOverlay"></div>
    <div id="PopupWindow">
<h1>Test</h1>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th width="333">Name</th>
<th width="249">Surname</th>
<th width="258">No<th width="182">Email</th>
</tr>
            <tr><td width="333"><input type="text" name="name" size="45"></td>
                <td width="249">
                <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-display-name="name" s-data-type="Integer" s-number-separators="x" i-maximum-length="12" --><input type="text" name="name2" size="10" maxlength="11"></td>
                <td width="258"> 
                &nbsp;<input type="text" name="name3" size="10" maxlength="11"></td>
                <td width="182"><input type="text" name="email" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="333">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="249">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
<tr><th width="333">Address</th>
    <th width="249">area 1</th>
<th colspan="2">area 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="333">
        <textarea rows="4" name="address" cols="39"></textarea></td>
                <td width="249">

        <input type="text" name="area1" size="20"><br>
        <b>area 3</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="area2" size="20"></td>
                <td colspan="2">

        <input type="text" name="area3" size="20"><br>
        <b>area 4</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="area4" size="20" maxlength="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
<th width="333">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="249">area 5</th>
<th colspan="2">area 6</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="333"> 

        &nbsp;</td>
                <td width="249"> 

        <input type="text" name="area5" size="20">
        <font color="#666666">(description)<br>
&nbsp;</font></td>
                <td colspan="2">

<input type="text" name="area6" size="20"><font color="#666666">(description)</font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
<th width="333">additional information</th>
<th width="249">&nbsp;</th>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">

                  <textarea name="message" cols="93" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="333" align="center">
                <p align="left">div 1 
<INPUT type="radio" name="hosting_package" id="hosting_package_1" value="1" class="validate[required] radio" onClick="HostingSpec(this);" /></td>
                <td width="249" align="center">
                <p align="left">div 2
              <input type="radio" name="hosting_package" id="hosting_package_2" value="2" class="validate[required] radio" onClick="HostingSpec(this);" />
                <br>
                </td>
<td colspan="2"><br>
</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="first_giz" style="display:none;">
<th width="333">Company</th>
<th width="249">
&nbsp;</th>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="first_giz_1" style="display:none;">
<td width="333"><select size="1" name="company">
        <option>test 1</option>
        <option>test 2</option>
        </select></td>
<td width="249"><br>
&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="second_giz" style="display:none;">
                <td width="333">
<b>company 2<br>
<br>
</b>
<select size="1" name="company2">
<option>test 1</option>
<option>test 2</option>
<option>test 3</option>
        </select><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="249">
<b>company 3<br>
</b>
<select size="1" name="company3">
        <option>test 1</option>
        <option>test 2</option>
        <option>test 3</option>
        </select><b><br>
<br>
area 7<br>
        </b><input type="text" name="test1" size="10"><b><br>
    area 8<br>
        </b>


        <input type="text" name="test2" size="10"><br>
&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2">
&nbsp;</td>
            </tr></table>
<table border="0" width="1151" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="1151">

    <tr>
        <td width="1151">

<blockquote>
    <blockquote>
        <blockquote>
            <blockquote>
                <blockquote>
                    <blockquote>
                        <blockquote>
                            <blockquote>
                                <blockquote>
                                    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" style="height: 50px; width: 200px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:bold; float:right"></blockquote>
                            </blockquote>
                        </blockquote>
                    </blockquote>
                </blockquote>
            </blockquote>
        </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
</blockquote>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form></p>
        <a href="javascript: void(0)" onClick="ClosePopup();">
        <font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 9pt">x</font></a><span style="font-size: 9pt">
        </span>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this link [wordpress simple form plugin and display in post with shortcode](http://www.mananpatel.in/wordpress-simple-form-plugin-and-display-in-post-with-shortcode.html)

This way you can include your php code directly into your post using with shortcode. I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind explaining the reason why? If you want to display a whole webpage within a blog post you're better off using an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, your intention is to include HTML, PHP, CSS, Javascript, or some other code within your wordpress post. There are many plugins which can do that. But, some of the plugins may not work as intended may be due to theme difference.

I recently came across with a plugin called [Crayon Syntax Highlighter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/installation/), it is working smothely with my multiple blogs. Install it following the instruction indicated in [here](http://ak.net84.net/) and try it.